# Implementing Azure AD B2C in an F# Saturn App

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe, saturn-framework

How do you implement Azure AD B2C in an F# Saturn app? I'm trying to follow the AzureADAuthSample that is included in the Saturn GitHub project but that appears to be directed at Azure AD, not Azure AD B2C.